# fs.write & read not updating

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, fs, discord.js

Basically, my code here is saying that if a user sends a message `!submit ___` then the file `leaderboard.json` will up their count by one.
This all works perfectly however say for example their count goes from 0 to 1, the next time that same person sends `!submit`, their count should go from 1 to 2 without me having to restart the script every time. This isn't happening unfortunately... I send `!submit` and my count goes from 0 to 1, but then I send it again and it stays going from 0 to 1.

**Leaderboard.json:**

```
{
    "usercount<@386679122614681600>": 0
}
```

**index.js:**

```
client.on('message', msg => {
   if (msg.content.startsWith("!submit ")){
      var shoe = msg.content.substr("!submit ".length);

      var fs = require('fs')
      fs.readFile('leaderboard.json', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
        if (err) {
          return console.log(err);
        }
        var user = msg.member;
        var usercount = 'usercount'+user
        var username = 'usercount'+user

        var LEADERBOARD = require('./leaderboard.json');
        var countvalue = LEADERBOARD[username]
        var countvalue2 = countvalue+1
        var replacetext = ('"'+usercount+'": '+countvalue).toString()
        var newtext = ('"'+usercount+'": '+(countvalue2)).toString()

        fs.writeFile('leaderboard.json', data.replace(replacetext, newtext), 
        'utf8', function () {
            if (err) return console.log(err);
        });
        console.log('NEW SUBMISSION: '+replacetext+' >>>> '+newtext)

     });
   }
```

**Here is what my console looks like after sending !submit twice:**

[image]

When technically the second line should go from 1 to 2, without me having to close and restart the script.

I know this may seem a bit complicated but any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why do you read `leaderboard.json` with `fs.readFile()`, then read it again with `require('./leaderboard.json')`.  That makes no sense at all.  Just read it with `require('./leaderboard.json')` (or better yet a library that does that asynchronously), modify the object, then write it out again using `fs.writeFile()` and `JSON.stringify()`.  No need to be trying to do some text replace in the middle of your JSON.  Probably the reason it doesn't work is the text replace doesn't work properly.

Comment: FYI, you also could easily have concurrency issues here where two `message` events are in flight at the same time and both trying to read/write the same file.  You may need a queue for update events.

Comment: I use the `require('./leaderboard.json')` so that I can gather the countvalue variable, is that not needed?

Comment: You should only read `leaderboard.json` once, not twice.

Comment: So do you have any recommendations as to how I can call `var countvalue = LEADERBOARD[username]` without using `var LEADERBOARD = require('./leaderboard.json');`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I'd suggest:

```
const fs = require('fs')

client.on('message', msg => {
    if (msg.content.startsWith("!submit ")) {
        let shoe = msg.content.substr("!submit ".length);

        // read leaderboard file and parse the JSON into a Javascript object
        fs.readFile('leaderboard.json', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Error reading leaderboard.json", err);
                return;
            }

            let leaderboard;
            try {
                leaderboard = JSON.parse(data);
            } catch(err) {
                console.log("Error parsing leaderboard JSON", err);
                return;
            }

            const user = msg.member;
            const username = 'usercount' + user;

            // make sure there's a count for this username
            let cnt = leaderboard[username];
            if (!cnt) {
                cnt = 0;
            }
            // increment the cnt
            ++cnt;

            // set the new count
            leaderboard[username] = cnt;

            // now write the data back to the file
            fs.writeFile('leaderboard.json', JSON.stringify(leaderboard), 'utf8', function() {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    return;
                }
                console.log(`New Submission for ${username}, cnt = ${cnt}`);
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Summary of changes:

1. Reads leaderboard.json only once using `fs.readFile()`
2. After reading the data, it converts it to JSON using `JSON.parse()`.
3. Initializes user cnt if not already in the file
4. Updates cnt in the Javsacript object directly
5. Writes out the changed object using `JSON.stringify()` to convert the object back to JSON
6. Puts new submission console message in `fs.writeFile()` success handler
7. Switch to `const` and `let` from `var`

Issues not yet incorporated:

1. Concurrency issues if multiple `message` events can be "in-flight" at once and conflict.
2. More complete error handling besides just stopping processing when there's an error (I'm not sure what your application should be doing in that case as that is application-specific).
3. Your `shoe` variable is not being used anywhere, not sure what it's doing there.